# Why BootSplash.storyboard is not showing up in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, splash-screen

Hello I'd like to put a splash screen in a react native app.
I followed the instructions from [here](https://blog.jscrambler.com/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-and-app-icon-in-react-native) and I checked the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-bootsplash?activeTab=readme) too.
The problem is that `BootSplash.storyboard` is not showing up in xcode!
And actually, from where am I supposed to drug it in the app folder?

[image: xcode and vscode screen shots]

[image]

I thought maybe it's because there is a `LaunchScreen.storyboard` already in the app. So it doesn't accept two files with `.storyboard`.
So I tried to just copy the code from `BootSplash.storyboard` to `LaunchScreen.storyboard`.
It works but now after the splash screen the app crashes.
I do use `hide()` in `App.tsx`.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => await RNBootSplash.hide({fade: true}))();
  }, [])
```

I even deleted completely the `BootSplash.storyboard`.
What could be the problem?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Credits to [React Native School](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PlubOKfi46o)
you can open Finder, find the file `BootSplash.storyboard` and drug it into your xCode project.

Note: I still followed the official [docs](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash) to launch the splash sceen.